# Using Visual Studio 2015 Community with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, dataprovider

This week I have installed the Visual Studio 2015 Community and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express.

I am trying to connect on my databases using the option Tools > Connect to Database, selecting Microsoft SQL Server on list, and I am not able to find my server name and databases, same after trying to write manually my server name and instance.

I read on the data provider description that the data provider is used only for 2005 or above. So, I installed the Microsoft OleDB 2 version 5, but I am not able to find my databases yet.

Do you have any suggestion of what do i need to do to be able to connect on it?

Comment: Vs2015 and SQ2014 should have no issues connecting to each other, support is native in .NET. Is SQL Express running? Is the SQL Browser service on your machine running? Can you connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio Express?

Comment: You should not need to rely on OleDB at all, the System.Data.SqlServer is all you should need. That and possibly the SQL Server Client Libraries which should have been installed with SQL Server Express.

Comment: Note that OLE DB is deprecated. Always use the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server (SqlClient) in managed code.

Comment: Wasn't i be able to connect without use a managed code using Connect to Database function?